# ngMessages: how to access error details (such as minlength, field name, etc)?

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

How can my `ngMessages` access information about the form error? Such as field name and other properties?

**Example:**

I've seen many examples that look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" minlength="5">
<div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error">
  <div ng-message="minlength">The value entered is too short</div>
</div>
```

**This is not a good error message because it doesn't tell the user how long the input should be.** It just tells them it's too short.

It should render something like: *"This field must be at least {{ minlength }} characters."*

Even better: *"{{ field }} must be at least {{ minlength }} characters."*

Having to define a different message for inputs of different minlengths is extremely not-DRY.

How can this be done with `ngMessages`?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the minlength value on the scope and then bind to it in the validation message.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" minlength="::myFieldMinlength">
<div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error">
    <div ng-message="minlength">This field must be at least {{::myFieldMinlength}} characters.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not totally sure I understand. Is `myFieldMinlength` a scope variable set from a controller, ex: `$scope.myFieldMinlength = 6` ?

Comment: Yep that's correct.It was the only way I could think of having the value available for the validation message.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. However, I'm not sure how it would work if the form has to inputs with different minlengths...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the same as jayChase suggested. It's definitely easiest way and as he has suggested using single binding won't be bad performance wise